# Webix Form getValues() returns undefined

Tags: javascript, html, web, webix

I'm using the JS libray Webix to build a front-end for an application. For login, I'm using their form. http://docs.webix.com/api__refs__ui.form.html

I'm having an issue using getValues() where it returns an undefined. I'll post my exact code.

Any help is appreciated.

```
<script>
            webix.ready(function(){
                webix.ui({
                    view:"form", 
                    id:'log_form',
                    width:300,
                    elements:[
                    { view:"text", id:"user", label:"Username"},
                    { view:"text", type:"password", label:"Password"},
                    { margin:5, cols:[
                        { view:"button", click:"testLogin", value:"Login"}
                    ]}
                    ]
                });

            });

            function testLogin()
            {
                var suppliedUser = $$('log_form').getValues().user;
                var suppliedPass = $$('log_form').getValues().password;
                console.log(suppliedUser);
                console.log(suppliedPass);
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `name` attribute for the form elements which values need to be included in the `getValues`

```
{ view:"text", name:"user", label:"Username"},
{ view:"text", name:"pass", type:"password", label:"Password"},
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been bashing my head against this for hours.